# How do I create two versions of the same component in react JS

Tags: reactjs, react-tsx

I'm beginning with react TS, and am trying to create a card with two "versions": one is before the user validates their profile and it has one input field that should be disabled, and the other is after the user validates the profile so the same input field should now be enabled. I thought about creating those two versions of the input field and then switching between them, is that the recommended approach? I need to be able to manipulate both the css and html of both versions to differentiate them. Thank you.

Comment: You can either make two different components or just pass props into one component that changes depending on what you pass. For instance, you pass `profileValidated` as a prop and if it's false disable the field and if it's true enable it.

Comment: Yep, that's what props are; properties that a component exposes to let other components know how its behavior and look can be controlled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do it, but instead of managing two separate components you can manage a flag which will let you toggle between `enabled` and `disabled` state of input field for that you need to use `useState` which will store a Boolean value in it.

```js
const [isValidated, setIsValidated] = useState(false);
...
return(
<>
   <input type="text" disabled={isValidated}/>
   ...
</>
);
```